# Output of js using d3 library is not visible, but no errors appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

HI:) I am trying to vizualize some data for my thesis, but it's my first experience with js, and it seems that I'm missing smth.
I would like to show each data point (each CNC) as a circle of the size that depends on the value specified in the column "CNC Length". On the x axes the points should be there where they are in the text (that is why x coordinate depends on "Sentence number").
The data is in tsv format, the head of it looks like this:

```html
N Subcorpus Type of Article Article Teil Sentence number CNC String CNC Length
0 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 8.0 multifaceted personality construct 3.0
1 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 11.0 alexithymia exhibit diﬃculties 3.0
2 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 14.0 multiple somatosensory pathways 3.0
3 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 35.0 open access article 3.0
4 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 68.0 heat pain threshold 3.0
5 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 75.0 emotion recognition impairment 3.0
6 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 97.0 lower TAS quartile 3.0
7 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 99.0 upper TAS quartile 3.0
8 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 132.0 warm threshold test 3.0
9 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 138.0 Pinprick pain threshold 3.0
10 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 139.0 laser stimulation device 3.0
11 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 155.0 numberintensity stimulus trials 4.0
12 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 155.0 numberintensity stimulus trials 4.0
13 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 167.0 orientation discrimination threshold 3.0
14 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 168.0 largest ridge width 3.0
15 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 194.0 stimulation duration constant 3.0
16 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 212.0 ulna styloid process 3.0
17 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 216.0 heartbeat perception task 3.0
18 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 222.0 heartbeat perception score 3.0
19 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 222.0 heartbeat perception intervals 3.0
20 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 225.0 heartbeat detection task 3.0
21 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 233.0 somatosensory detection threshold 3.0
22 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 235.0 detection threshold intensities 3.0
23 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 260.0 heat pain threshold 3.0
24 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 281.0 thermal detection test 3.0
25 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 309.0 further linear regression 3.0
26 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 318.0 strong group diﬀerence 3.0
27 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 330.0 Mean pleasantness ratings 3.0
28 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 342.0 emotion recognition diﬃculties 3.0
29 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 351.0 null result cannot rule 4.0
30 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 354.0 warmth perception threshold 3.0
31 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 371.0 speciﬁc receptor types 3.0
32 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 373.0 warmstimulus dimensions 3.0
33 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 383.0 physical warmthalsoOur study 3.0
34 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 396.0 c-tactile mechanoreceptor pathway 3.0
35 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 398.0 aﬀective touch test 3.0
36 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 406.0 pleasantness ratings overall 3.0
37 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 410.0 body mass index 3.0
38 biology_intros Quant/Qual -Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 412.0 aﬀective touch test 3.0
267 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 1.0 human startle response 3.0
268 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 2.0 eye blink reﬂex 3.0
269 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Intro> 2.0 body startle reﬂex 3.0
270 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 91.0 Neurobehavioralelectrocutaneous stimuli 3.0
271 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 120.0 stimulusonset asynchrony 3.0
272 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Middle> 134.0 EMG data processing 3.0
273 biology_intros Quant/Qual Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt <Conclusion> 241.0 Disclosure statement None 3.0
```

The code is as follows:

```js
var w = 600;
var h = 300;
d3.tsv("df.tsv", function(d) {
 return{
  Sentence_number : +d["Sentence number"],
  CNC_Length : +d["CNC Length"],
  article : d.Article,
  part: d.Teil
 };
 
}, function(data){
 var padding = 20;
 var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    //.domain([3, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["CNC Length"]; })])
    .domain([3, 7])
    .range([2, 40]);
 var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    //.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Sentence number"]; })]) //input domain
    .domain([0, 1000]) //input domain
    .range([padding, w-padding*2]); //output range
 var canv = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h)
 canv.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .filter(function(d) { return (d["Article"] == "Deficient-prepulse-inhibition-of-the-startle-reflex-in-sch_2017_Biological-P.txt") })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
   return xScale(d["Sentence number"]);
   })
  .attr("cy", h/2)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
   return "rgb(255, 0, " + d["CNC Length"] * 10 + ", 0.75)";
   })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
   return rScale(d["CNC Length"]);
  })
});
```

The problem is that I see no errors in console, and nothing appears on the screen (I tried working with artificial data creating it per hand in js and it worked, but when I imported the data, something went wrong).

I would be thankful for any advice:)

Comment: in the callback what does `data` look like when you dump it on the console?

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: @altocumulus, I use thi one: https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

Comment: console.log(data); gives this: (2286) [{…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0:
CNC_Length: 3
Sentence_number: 8
article: "-Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt"
part: "<Intro>"
__proto__: Object
1: {Sentence_number: 11, CNC_Length: 3, article: "-Lacking-warmth---Alexithymia-trait-is-related-to-warm-spe_2017_Biological-P.txt", part: "<Intro>"}
2: {Sentence_number: 14, CNC_Length: 3, article: "-Lacking-warmth---....and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hints! I found my mistake!
I was addressing the columns by their old names, i.e. I should use d.article instead of d.Article, d.CNC_Length instead of d["CNC Length"] and so on, cause I have the names of the columns in the array differ from how the were called in my tsv, cause I am changing them here:

```
return{
    Sentence_number : +d["Sentence number"],
    CNC_Length : +d["CNC Length"],
    article : d.Article,
    part: d.Teil
};
```

Moreover, there was a problem with filter. It should be used at the point where I select the data, i.e:

```
canv.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) { return (d.article === "Chronic-traumatic-stress-impairs-memory-in-mice--Potential-ro_2017_Behaviour.txt") }))
    .enter()
```

Now it all works, and I am developing it further:)